# Recording of the played audio stream

Tags: android

There is a link to the online radio http://variant.fm:8000/LOVE-32. The application implements the playback of this audio stream with the help of exoplayer. I click play - play starts, and when you click on stop - stops. With this, everything is fine.

I want to make two more buttons "Record" and "Stop". When you click on the record, you should start writing to the file of this stream, and when you press the stop, the recording ends.

For example, the stream is playing and clicking the record: an mp3 file was created on the phone in a folder, and until the stop is stopped, the stream is written to this file, and when the stop is stopped, the recording stops and we have the final mp3 file.

How to implement this? Tell me, please, what articles to read, what examples to look at? In many applications of online radio in the playbook, this is implemented, and I want to implement the same functionality in my application.